# What are common fonts for TV sports score banners?

Tags: fonts

I'm working on a project that needs a font very similar to the types used in television broadcasts of sports games to display the score and other info.  I would love to know if there are any industry standard or common fonts, particularly in NBA broadcasts.

Example:

[image: sports]

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know if there is some kind of standard for fonts in NBA broadcasts, but obviously they have to maintain readability even if they are small and pixelated.
The apertures and counters should be big and easily recognizable.

The *Frutiger* family was designed for the guidance system of the airport Charles de Gaulle and should work just fine.

Maybe you also want to look into the *Thesis* family. It’s used by a major broadcaster here in Germany and has tons of different faces.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit old, but I know that ESPN (and now CBS too) have been using Klavika a lot lately.